# Método Booleano Calcular el importe del producto y sumatorio total

Tags: java

Buenas tardes compañer@s:

A ver si me pueden ayudar. Tengo problema con este método "public boolean registroProducto" el tema es que no sé como calcular el importe que se tiene que ir acumulando. Sería multiplicar la cantidad, de tipo entero, por el precio que está dentro de un array de tipo Producto, que se encuentran en la segunda posición. A ver si algún máquina me echa un cable.

```
/**
 * Registra la compra de un producto, obteniendo su precio unitario de la tabla 
 * de productos e incrementa el importe añadiendo el producto del precio unitario
 * por el nº de unidades adquiridas
 * @param producto -> Nombre del producto adquirido
 * @param cantidad -> Número de unidades adquiridas
 * @return -> TRUE si el producto existe y se registra la compra, o
 * FALSE en caso contrario
 */

package EjerciciosParciales;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Compra {
    
private Producto[] productos = {
        new Producto("Tornillo", 3.0f), 
        new Producto("Tuerca", 2.0f), 
        new Producto("Remache", 1.0f), 
        new Producto("Clavo", 1.5f)
};

private float importe = 0.0f; 

public Compra(Producto[] productos, float importe) {
    this.productos = productos;
    this.importe = importe;
}

public Producto[] getProductos() {
    return productos;
}

public void setProductos(Producto[] productos) {
    this.productos = productos;
}

public void setImporte(float importe) {
    this.importe = importe;
}

public boolean registroProducto(Producto productos, int unidades){
    boolean registrar=false;
    if(productos !=null) {
        importe= (float)unidades;
        this.importe=+importe;
        registrar=true;
    }
    return registrar;
}

public boolean Comprar( String producto, int cantidad ) {
    return true;
}

public float getImporte() {
    return this.importe; 
}

}
```

**EDIT**
Adjunto el código de la clase `Principal`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Principal {
    

    // Solicita un valor entero al usuario, lo valida, y lo retorna
    public static int pedirValor( Scanner scr, String mensaje ) {
        return 0; 
    }
    
    // Solicita al usuario que responda "S" o "N" a una pregunta y devuelve un valor lógico TRUE/FALSE
    public static boolean pedirConfirmacion( Scanner scr, String mensaje ) {
        return true; 
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scr = new Scanner( System.in);
        String producto; 
        int cantidad; 
        
        Compra compra=new Compra();// Instancia un objeto Compra
        do {
            System.out.println("Que producto quieres adquirir?");// Pide nombre de producto adquirido
            producto=scr.nextLine();
            
            System.out.println("Cuantas unidades quieres?");// Pide cantidad de unidades adquiridas
            cantidad=scr.nextInt();
            
            if(producto.!=null){// Registra compra -> Si no existe producto muestra mensaje de error. 
            }
        } while ( true ); // Solicita confirmacion para añadir otro producto a la compra. 
        // Muestra cuantia total de la compra. 
    }

}
```

Comment: No tiene mucho sentido lo que estas haciendo en tu método ``registroProducto`` porque pasas como parámetro unidades haces un ``cast``  float para asignar a importe, se supone que ``importe`` debe ser cantidad*precioUnitario.

Comment: Joshin, gracias por contestar. Ya sé que no tiene sentido. Esa linea de código está a medias por implementar. Ese casting era por que tenia que multiplicar un entero con un float... Pero ya sé que está mal

Comment: Supongo que la clase `Producto` tiene un *getter* para obtener su precio, entonces lo que tienes que hacer es algo así más o menos: `this.importe=+productos.getPrecio()*cantidad;`, asumiendo que el *getter* se llama `getPrecio()` si se llama de otro modo lo modificas y listo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta tus requisitos te dejo un código funcional, solo lo hago porque tienes ciertas ideas de como trabajar y compartiste el avance de lo que realizaste.
Antes de compartir el código quiero darte algunas observaciones:

1. No indicas en que clase va estar tu método `main`, el código que te comparto el main está dentro de la clase `Compra`, por eso no necesito de los métodos set y get de los `atributos de clase`, en cambio si el método main va estar en otra clase distinta sí necesitaría esos métodos.
2. Suponiendo que ya tienes creado tu clase `Producto` con los atributos para el nombre y el precio unitario y sus respectivos métodos set y get.

```
public class Compra {

    private Producto[] productos = {
            new Producto("Tornillo", 3.0f), 
            new Producto("Tuerca", 2.0f), 
            new Producto("Remache", 1.0f), 
            new Producto("Clavo", 1.5f)
    };    
    private float importe= 0.0f;

    public float getImporte() {
        return importe;
    } 

    public boolean registroProducto(String producto,int cantidad){
        boolean registrar=false;
        for (Producto producto1 : productos) {
            if (producto1.getNombre().equals(producto)) {
                this.importe = importe + producto1.getPrecioUnitario() * cantidad;  
                registrar=true;                
            }
        } 
        return registrar;        
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
He modificado la clase `Compra` y agregado la clase `Principal`

```
public class Principal { 
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scr = new Scanner( System.in);        
        int cantidad;        
        Compra compra=new Compra();// Instancia un objeto Compra
        
        String rpta;
        do{
            System.out.println("Ingrese nombre del producto? ");
            String nombre=scr.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Cuantos unidades desea comprar? ");
            cantidad=Integer.parseInt(scr.nextLine());    
            if(compra.registroProducto(nombre,cantidad)){
                System.out.println("Compra Registrada");
            }
            else System.out.println("Compra no Registrada");            
            
            System.out.println("Desea realizar otra compra? ");
            rpta=scr.nextLine();            
        }while(rpta.equalsIgnoreCase("s")); 
        
        System.out.println("El importe a pagar es: "+compra.getImporte());
    } 
 }
```

Comment: Buenas @Joshin,, el main esta en otra clase. Por eso no está.

Comment: @Arkaitxiki he agregado el código de la clase ``Principal`` y editado a clase ``Compra``